# Separate build step for Java file - Maven

Tags: java, maven

Within a larger Maven project, I have a Java file (AudioFileBuilder.java) that generates audio files from the Google Cloud Text-to-Speech service. It can execute from its own main() class; however, this file references an enumeration within the project (that other project source files depend on).

I am creating a fat JAR (JAR-with-dependencies), .exe file (Windows), and .app file (macOS) for the main project. I would like to exclude the AudioFileBuilder.java file AND the associated Google Cloud Text-to-Speech dependency in the JAR, exe, and app files. However, I still need the AudioFileBuilder.java file to run every time the project is built.

Here is a link to my project's current POM file (the project is open-source):
https://github.com/hadi16/GamesForTheBlind/blob/Alex-Branch/pom.xml

This is my current POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.up</groupId>
    <artifactId>Games_For_Blind</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-texttospeech</artifactId>
            <version>0.117.0-beta</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>gamesforblind.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/xsd-out</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- To generate the phrase audio files. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>

                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath/>
                        <argument>gamesforblind.synthesizer.AudioFileBuilder</argument>
                    </arguments>

                    <environmentVariables>
                        <GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS>google_api_key.json</GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Create executable Windows file. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <jar>${project.build.directory}/dist/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
                            <outfile>${project.build.directory}/dist/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.exe</outfile>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>gamesforblind.Main</mainClass>
                            </classPath>
                            <jre>
                                <minVersion>12</minVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <copyright>2019</copyright>
                                <fileVersion>${project.version}</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                                <productVersion>${project.version}</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>${project.version}</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                                <internalName>${project.name}</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.exe</originalFilename>
                                <companyName>University of Portland</companyName>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.perdian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>macosappbundler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <plist>
                        <CFBundleDisplayName>Games For The Blind</CFBundleDisplayName>
                        <JVMMainClassName>gamesforblind.Main</JVMMainClassName>
                        <JVMVersion>12</JVMVersion>
                        <CFBundleDisplayName>Games For The Blind</CFBundleDisplayName>
                        <CFBundleName>Games For The Blind</CFBundleName>
                    </plist>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE:**

I divided the project into two separate modules: "audio-builder" & "application" - as suggested by Welsh.

However, I have a Java enumeration ("Phrases.java") that both the audio-builder & application uses. The audio-builder needs this file to know which audio phrases are currently in the program, while the rest of the application needs this to load in said audio files & call the playback of these files.

So, this made me add the "audio-builder" module as a dependency for the "application" module. Since the Google Cloud dependency is needed at compile-time, this means that it is bundled in the generated JAR, app, and exe files.

These changes can be found here: https://github.com/hadi16/GamesForTheBlind/tree/Maven-Fixes

Root POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.up</groupId>
    <artifactId>games-for-the-blind</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <modules>
        <module>games-for-the-blind/audio-builder</module>
        <module>games-for-the-blind/application</module>
    </modules>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Audio-builder POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.up</groupId>
    <artifactId>audio-builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-texttospeech</artifactId>
            <version>0.117.0-beta</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>

                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath/>
                        <argument>builder.AudioFileBuilder</argument>
                    </arguments>

                    <environmentVariables>
                        <GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS>google_api_key.json</GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application POM file (note the dependency to audio-builder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.up</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.0</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.up</groupId>
            <artifactId>audio-builder</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>12</source>
                    <target>12</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dist</outputDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>gamesforblind.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/xsd-out</directory>
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Create executable Windows file. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-clui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <jar>
                                ${project.build.directory}/dist/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar
                            </jar>
                            <outfile>${project.build.directory}/dist/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.exe
                            </outfile>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>gamesforblind.Main</mainClass>
                            </classPath>
                            <jre>
                                <minVersion>12</minVersion>
                                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <copyright>2019</copyright>
                                <fileVersion>${project.version}</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                                <productVersion>${project.version}</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>${project.version}</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                                <internalName>${project.name}</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.exe</originalFilename>
                                <companyName>University of Portland</companyName>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.perdian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>macosappbundler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <plist>
                        <CFBundleDisplayName>Games For The Blind</CFBundleDisplayName>
                        <JVMMainClassName>gamesforblind.Main</JVMMainClassName>
                        <JVMVersion>12</JVMVersion>
                        <CFBundleDisplayName>Games For The Blind</CFBundleDisplayName>
                        <CFBundleName>Games For The Blind</CFBundleName>
                    </plist>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bundle</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Seems that you mix up two projects. One project the helper project (build an executable for running your AudioFileBuilder.java), the other one is your main project which needs to run your first helper project to provide the generated resources.

Comment: Can you create multiple Maven projects in a single POM file? It is my understanding that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you split your projects into two sub projects, so you would have for example:

```
games-for-the-blind/
   pom.xml
   audio-builder/
      pom.xml
   application/
      pom.xml
```

Then what you can do is have the `audio-builder` package output the required files into the `application/resources` directory and have it listed first in the main `pom.xml` file.

This would allow you to distribute the `application` resultant files that would not contain any of the details of the `audio-builder` project.

Comment: Thank you, Welsh! I updated my post with my progress on splitting up the project into modules.

Comment: If you have classes that need to be in both then create an additional `api` sub project and make both the `audio-builder` and `application` depend on it. This would allow you to share code between them and again not include the builder in the main distributable.,